# Edit Memory Address via c#

Tags: c#, inline-assembly

i want to edit an active app (edit a memory address),

on address `00498D45` i want to edit its value

currect value :

```
MOV BYTE PTR SS:[EBP-423],7
```

to

updated value:

```
 MOV BYTE PTR SS:[EBP-423],8
```

what i got till now is this (searched about it on the net and this how far i got):

thanks in advance!

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    [Flags]

        public enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint

{
    All = 0x001F0FFF,
    Terminate = 0x00000001,
    CreateThread = 0x00000002,
    VMOperation = 0x00000008,
    VMRead = 0x00000010,
    VMWrite = 0x00000020,
    DupHandle = 0x00000040,
    SetInformation = 0x00000200,
    QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
    Synchronize = 0x00100000
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, uint nSize, out int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, out int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 CloseHandle(IntPtr hProcess);

Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("My Apps Name").FirstOrDefault();

public static bool WriteMemory(Process process, int address, long value, out int bytesWritten)
{
    IntPtr hProc = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, process.Id);

    byte[] val = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);

    bool worked = WriteProcessMemory(hProc, new IntPtr(address), val, (UInt32) val.LongLength, out bytesWritten);

    CloseHandle(hProc);

    return worked;
}
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: how i can do the edit that i wanted, i mean the ASM updated from the currect value to the updated value - i am new to ASM so i dunno if i set up the value etc right.

Comment: @Yahia He wants to edit a byte in a process's memory arbitrarily.

Comment: What software are you trying to hack?

Comment: Does it work, and you are asking for a code review or is not not working (and if it does not work is it just you don't see the behavior or do you get an error)

Comment: Won't this cause a segmentation fault?

Comment: @Evo510 If done wrong, yes. but In-process memory editing is a common enough thing (it is what the debugger is doing when you debug).

Comment: hi, i dont try to hack a program but to manipulate my game server, when i edit this address it control the text color - by changing it i able to create texts in more colors then the default

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Excuse my lack of knowledge on the debugger, but doesn't the debugger usually run an application in a way that allows it to do so? If this is a production application won't this code be trying to reach a page file it doesn't have access too.

Comment: hi, i didnt tried it yet becouse i dunno how to implant the change i want to the code, thats why i asked if it will work with the correct code and if yes how i should put it?

Comment: So, that instruction is `C6 85 59 FE FF FF 07`. Write an 8 (as byte) to the offset of the 07.

Comment: @Evo510 To be able to execute things like breakpoints the debugger must inject code ([using `int 3` to break](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_%28x86_instruction%29#INT_3)). Here is a really good [indepth article](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/01/27/how-debuggers-work-part-2-breakpoints/) explaining the nuts and bolts of how it works.

Comment: how it should be then?  something like that?             Process[] process = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyApp");

            WriteMemory(process,00498D45,C6 85 59 FE FF FF 07);

Comment: @Dan272 no, it's already that, write 8 to `0x00498D45 + 6` (supposedly the address of that 7)

Comment: how does WriteMemory(procces,address,value) should be look like? i didnt got it.

Answer (score 3):

From your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313756/):

```
WriteMemory(Process process,00498D45 , MOV BYTE PTR SS:[EBP-423],8)
```

There are so many problems with this, I don't know where to begin. First of all, that's not anywhere near correct C# syntax.

1. You're calling a function, but you have `Process` there like it's a signature.
2. `00498D45` is not a valid constant in any base. If you mean hex, (which you probably do since you're dealing with addresses) then like all other C-like languages, that should be expressed as `0x00498D45`.
3. That's x86 assembly code in ASCII (but it's not in a string, you just have a mess). You can't just plop ASCII assembly code into another process's address space!

Perhaps you should do a little more research on how compilation, and assembly work when building a program, and the guts of what your CPU is actually doing when it's executing a program.  Also, I recommend reading through the sample code you've very obviously taken from somewhere and try to *understand* it. You'll be way better off learning what's going on, than asking everyone to help fix the stuff you've cobbled together. `</rant>`

Anyway, after you assemble your code, it looks like this (re dis-assembled):

```
C68559FEFFFF08    mov byte [ebp-0x1a7],0x8
```

That means that your instruction is actually the string of bytes `C6 85 59 FE FF FF 08`. So that is what you need to write into your target application.

This is the basis of what you're trying to do:

```
byte[] new_instr = new byte[] {0xC6, 0x85, 0x59, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x08};
IntPtr target_addr = (IntPtr)0x00498D45;

int bytesWritten;
WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, target_addr, new_instr, (UInt32)new_instr.Length, out bytesWritten);
```

The `WriteMemory` memory function you've copy-and-pasted *won't* help you here. The problem is, it only writes a `long` which is 4 bytes. You need to write 7 bytes. So you'll either have to modify that function to use a `byte[]` parameter, or do it yourself.

---

I admire your ambition, but you should really start a bit lower. Write some C# code to get yourself familiar with programming in a C-like language. Then write some C to get familiar with crashing when you don't do things perfectly. Then try dabbling in assembly - perhaps writing small inline pieces into your C code. Finally then, you'll be ready to go hacking around the instructions of other running processes.

Comment: What's wrong with writing 4 bytes? Only 1 byte actually changes, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an injection library like [MemorySharp](http://binarysharp.com/products/memorysharp/) (I'm the author). All these functions are wrapped within a handy API, integrating an assembler (FASM syntax). Thus this piece of code perform what you want :

```
using (var m = new MemorySharp(ApplicationFinder.FromProcessName("My App").First()))
{
    m.Assembly.Inject("MOV BYTE [EBP-423],8", new IntPtr(0x00498D45));
}
```

Comment: Your library doesn't seem to work, for a reason. When I try using the code you displayed on an executable process (with different instructions and address), I'm getting the error: "An error occured during FASM was assembling mnemonics. Error code: -118 (Invalid Expression); Error line: 3; Error offset: 21". Any idea why it could happen?