# Convert assembly to Hex?

Tags: c#, assembly

I need to edit a memory address with the following expression:

```
MOV BYTE PTR SS:[EBP-423],8
```

now from my research i found that

```
 Convert.ToByte('a')
```

should do this work,  but i cant make it to work properly, so i tried with diffrent method -

```
static private String convertAsciiTextToHex(String i_asciiText)
{
    StringBuilder sBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < i_asciiText.Length; i++)
    {
        sBuffer.Append(Convert.ToInt32(i_asciiText[i]).ToString("x"));
    }
    return sBuffer.ToString().ToUpper();
}

string Xax = convertAsciiTextToHex("MOV BYTE PTR SS:[EBP-423],8");
            Console.WriteLine(Xax);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

now i get wrong value on Xax, i should get the value of :

```
C6 85 59 FE FF FF 08
```

but i am getting

```
Xax = "4D4F562042595445205054522053533A5B4542502D3432335D2C38"
```

Comment: You need to learn to walk before you can run. Try starting here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/106937/where-can-i-learn-more-about-low-level-programming/107161#107161

Answer (score 6):

You're not really asking to convert ASCII text to a hex representation of the text. You're asking how to convert assembly language into machine code.

For that, you need an assembler.

Even then, I wouldn't expect you'd actually want the hex representation - you'd just want the bytes of the machine code.

Even *then* you'd have to work out how to execute that machine code.

I completely agree with the [answer you received here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16330964/22656) in terms of taking things one step at a time - it feels like you're trying to bypass really learning about assembly language (and the general concepts involved) when you should instead take a step back.

Comment: oh ic, thanks for the input - can i do it via c# only only via assembler? thanks agian.

Comment: @Dan272: You've got assembly language, so you'd need an assembler. But I really think you're going down the wrong path here. Don't just latch onto one part of an answer without understanding it - you've been given other answers around how to modify memory in a process from C# if you *really* need to, although frankly I'm dubious about the purpose of this anyway. What are you *really* trying to achieve, as a higher level goal?

Comment: +1. @Dan272 - it is definitely possible to write assembler in C#. There are plenty of tools to simplify work involved, but even writing it completely by hand for some basic assembly language should be doable in reasonable time (probably would work as task to one semester).

Comment: well i try to learn and read what i can about assembly, but as i am new unfamiliar to it, its not exactly floating. but also i have an end point atm thats why i not "stoping back" and rushing over my head now - i know its not the healthy way to learn things atm...

Comment: @Dan272: It's not a healthy way to learn *or* a healthy way to achieve anything. Urgency doesn't alter this... and you *still* haven't told us what your bigger goal is. You'd be likely to get a lot further (and quicker) if you'd explain that, and ask for suggestions of the best way to achieve it.

Comment: @JonSkeet my end goal is like that: that specific address control the "color" text that will be displayed on the game client text box. - the address i edit is on the "game server app" and it sending a global msg to every1 ingame with a specific color - i wise to change that color to 4-5 other colors, each time to diffrent color. the only way to do so it either to start write new commands to the game server app - to use diffrent kinds of colors under each command (will need to write it on ASM). or memory edit that address each time before i do a "global notice" to the specific color i want, ty

Comment: @Dan272: So do you control both the client and the server? If so, why not tackle this in a rather more sensible way than trying to mess with memory directly? It sounds like this basically needs to be part of the protocol between the client and the server, and the server code then decides which colour to send.

Comment: becouse i dont have the source code of the game server side app, so i will need to write the new commands with ASM, and as u saw my ASM level is not exactly great atm, the fix i am doing here is temporary as after i will reach a sufficient assembly level i will write down those commands - could time few weeks - months. thats  why i wanted a "patch fix" that will work also.

Comment: @Dan272: Making changes to code you don't own is a very dodgy business. It's hard, may have legal consequences depending on your location, and I'd strongly advise you to stop right now.